# change duration android audio player

Tags: android, audio, duration

I created an audio player, and I have a class in my project for working with duration. How can one make sure that totalDuration has counted in the opposite direction?

```
public class Utilities {
public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds){
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";
    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int)( milliseconds / (1000*60*60));
    int minutes = (int)(milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if(hours > 0){
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }
    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if(seconds < 10){
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    }else{
        secondsString = "" + seconds;}
    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}

public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration, long totalDuration){
    Double percentage = (double) 0;
    long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration / 1000);
    long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);
    // calculating percentage
    percentage =((((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100);
    // return percentage
    return percentage.intValue();
}

public int progressToTimer(int progress, int totalDuration) {
    int currentDuration = 0;
    totalDuration = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);
    currentDuration = (int) ((((double)progress) / 100) * totalDuration);
    // return current duration in milliseconds
    return currentDuration * 1000;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you could edit your question to better explain?  Do you want the currentDuration to count down from totalDuration to 0?

I think you might want this:

```
currentDuration = (int) totalDuration - ((((double)progress) / 100) * totalDuration);
```